# PHP how to fetch data from textarea

Tags: php

This is my code..I want to fetch data from textarea..
Im using ckeditor to make it active i have use contenteditable="true"...but when i use this it is not able to fetch textarea value

```
<body>
    <form action="sample_posteddata.php" method="post">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="headerLeft">
                    <h2 id="sampleTitle" contenteditable="true">
                    <textarea name="article_title" ></textarea>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="columns">
            <div id="column1">
                <div contenteditable="true">
                    <textarea name="article_body" ></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

from this code it gives me error of undefined index article_body
please suggest me with some solution

Comment: try `print_r($_POST)` in `sample_posteddata.php`

Comment: @DhinjuDivakaran it shows me Array ( [submit] => Submit )..what should i do to fetch textarea values

Comment: It should be `$_POST['article_title']`

Comment: due to <div> and <h2> it is not able to fetch the data from textarea...but i can't remove div tag..waht is other way to do this

Comment: Close the </h2> before textarea, not after.

Comment: @volodya this makes my text-editor in active

Comment: @karsh found solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can fetch form data by form attribute `name` Try this

```
$_POST['article_body']` and `$_POST['article_title']
```

**OR**

```
$_REQUEST['article_body']` and `$_REQUEST['article_title']
```

Comment: i tried this but it shows me error such as undefined index

Comment: now to recognize its due to  contenteditable="true" when i remove this from my code it is able to fetch the code, contenteditable="true" is necessary bcoz it awkes my text editor

Answer (score 0):

**Remember ckeditor may change the name of that textarea.**

Dump post data using

```
echo'<pre>'; 
print_r($_POST);
```

And check the exact variable name.

**OR**

For exact name you can use inspect element (or press f12)

Comment: the code is working when i remove contenteditable="true",form fetches the textarea value bt when i add contenteditable="true" it doesnot work